# convertime datetime object am-pm

Tags: php

I have a date time object as:

```
$startTime = new DateTime();
$startTime->setTime($weekTimeArr[1][0]["hour"], $weekTimeArr[1][0]["minute"]);
$startTime->format('h:i a');
$endTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('IST'));
```

Now this thing works fine and I get values as `05:00AM`, `02:00AM`....
But how can I tell this logic to return values in `PM` when a particular condition is met.

Example :

```
if(a == true) {
   $startTime = new DateTime();
   $startTime->setTime($weekTimeArr[1][0]["hour"], $weekTimeArr[1][0]["minute"]);
   $startTime->format('h:i a');
   $endTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('IST'));
}
```

now if `a==true` then it should return 5PM instead of 5AM.

Comment: What is the value of `$weekTimeArr[1][0]["hour"]` ? AM and PM is depend on the value of `$weekTimeArr[1][0]["hour"]` if it will be 12+ means 15 then it will return 3PM and so on.

Comment: Just add 12 hours

Comment: `$weekTimeArr[1][0]["hour"]` is just a string which returns GMT like 8.

Comment: So, your `$weekTimeArr[1][0]` contains a 12 hour time, and `a` is a flag that tells you whether that time represents AM or PM…?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. You have to add the 12 in the hours if your condition is true. Code is below:

```
if(a == true) {
   $hour = $weekTimeArr[1][0]["hour"] + 12;
   $startTime = new DateTime();
   $startTime->setTime($hour, $weekTimeArr[1][0]["minute"]);
   $startTime->format('h:i a');
   $endTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('IST'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is unclear on what is the value of `$weekTimeArr[1][0]["hour"]` but in order to convert a given time from AM to PM you need to do this

```
$startTime->modify('+12 hours')->format('h:i a');
```